# iOS Twitter API

Tags: ios, twitter

I have done some looking around at some other post on here but none of them seem to work either. So, my question is using the Twitter API built into iOS, how do I include the text from a label into the initial Twitter text.

I have:

```
[tweetSheet setInitialText:@"I have just generated the following numbers from The Lottery App: %@", label1.text];
```

Could anyone help? - Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no Twitter API built into Xcode.

Comment: [Here](http://dummycode.com/b/3) is a great post on integrating Twitter API with iOS.

Comment: Yep - that sure is a great access denied screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply :

```
NSString *initialText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I have just generated the following numbers from The Lottery App:%@",label1.text]
[tweetSheet setInitialText:initialText];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I have just generated the following numbers from The Lottery App: %@", label1.text]];
```